# Using ppp0 via VPN for everything but ftp

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ftp

I have an ubuntu server I use to wget certain files from the internet via a VPN. I have set the VPN up using PPP0 and currently adjust the route like this:

```
 sudo route add default ppp0
```

Everything is working fine with the vpn connection, but now I would like to route FTP traffic via eth0 and not the VPN.

I tried

```
  sudo route add default eth0
```

for the period I was using FTP but lost the internet connection until

```
   ifdown eth0 ifup eth0
```

was called.

Clearly I am doing something wrong.

Ideal solution would be to always route all FTP via eth0 if that is easy, if not then what should I add to my bash script to route the traffic back to eth0 while the FTP upload completes (at which point I can go back to route add default ppp0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called Policy Based Routing. Google will return you lots of information on this topic, and it is too complicated to answer completely in a ServerFault answer post.

The 10,000 foot view is that you:

1. Create additional routing tables in the kernel.
2. Configure each routing table to use a different default route (one for your normal connection, one for your VPN).
3. Using iptables, identify and `mark` every packet according to your rules/policy.
4. Assign the marks you used in step 3 to tell the kernel which routing table to use for each packet.

The very basic commands to achieve this:

```
echo 200 novpn >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add table 200 default via 192.0.2.1
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -d server.example.com -j MARK --set-mark 200
ip rule add fwmark 200 table novpn
```

Replace 192.0.2.1 with your default router on your local network.

Comment: @andy NB. that it is complicated because "routing" and "FTP" exist at different networking layers ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Description_of_OSI_layers ). Being picky, fukawi2's example does not *'route FTP'*, it routes *'TCP traffic to server.example.com on TCP port 21, regardless of whether it is FTP or not'*, and it will ignore FTP traffic to other sites and other ports. Sometimes this doesn't matter, sometimes it does.

Comment: Good clarification @TessellatingHeckler -- a perfect example of why this is far too complicated a topic to explain fully in a SF post ;)

Comment: Note that active FTP does not stay on Port 21 for very long. I'm not familiar with iptables so I don't know if it is smart enough to know to "expand" the rule to cover the new ports after the port negotiations.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Good point. iptables can `mark` the connection (rather than individual packets), and then the `related` connection type can maintain the PBR for the additional connection. But none of that is covered in my answer and requires further reading.